# Powershell Script to update Date

Tags: powershell

I would like to know how to update date field from CSV file.Attached the code while debugging I can able to publish date is updated but its not visible in Content tree.

script:

```
$currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
$currentItem["Publish Date"] = $row."publish date"
$currentItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

screenshot after running script:

[image]

Comment: How do you get $currentItem? Do you edit the item in the correct language?

Answer (score 4):

As far as editing an item, your script looks to be doing what it needs to, but I'm guessing the actual date value is not something Sitecore recognized for a `Date` type field. Depending on the date format your CSV contains, you will likely need to utilize the `Sitecore.DateUtil` class to parse it into something that field can accept:

```
$currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
$csvDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($row."publish date","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",[Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
$currentItem["Publish Date"] = [Sitecore.DateUtil]::ToIsoDate($csvDate)
$currentItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Comment: got this error message Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @sindu I updated my answer to include the exact parsing format from your answer

Answer (score 2):

In Sitecore, when you need to edit an item using the Sitecore API, you first need to put the item in *Editing* mode.  To do this, you'll can call `.Editing.BeginEdit()` before attempting to modify the item.  Then end it with `.Editing.EndEdit()`.

```
$currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
$currentItem["Publish Date"] = $row."publish date"
$currentItem.Editing.EndEdit()
```

You can also format your call like this (brackets removed) and SPE will take care of all the necessary usages of `.Editing.BeginEdit` and `.Editing.EndEdit`:

```
$currentItem."Publish Date" = $row."publish date"
```

Additional information on working with items using SPE can be found on the [SPE Documentation site](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items)

Comment: I tried with editing only its not working

Comment: Are you able to edit any other fields?  Single-Line text field for example.

Answer (score 1):

This format is working for me:

```
$csvDate = [datetime]::ParseExact("23/09/2015 05:41:27","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",[Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US"))        
$currentItem["Publish Date"] = [Sitecore.DateUtil]::ToIsoDate($csvDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

This format is working for me - I had to add ".Value" to the item reference.

```
if ( $ValidFrom" -ne "" ) {
    $itemEdit.Fields["__Valid from"].Value = [Sitecore.DateUtil]::ToIsoDate($ValidFrom")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your date script code as below:

```
 #Add leading zero into the day and month to avoid error in ParseExact
        if($row.CreatedDate.Trim() -ne "")
        {
            $oldDate = $row.CreatedDate.Trim().Replace('/','-')
            $newDate = $oldDate.Split("-")[0].ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')+'-'+$oldDate.Split("-")[1].ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')+'-'+$oldDate.Split("-")[2].ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
            $csvDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($newDate,"dd-MM-yyyy",[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

            $item["PublishDate"] = [Sitecore.DateUtil]::ToIsoDate($csvDate)     
        }
```

In the CSV file if the Date Column field values will be separated with `-` then if would word fine. If the date column field value will be separated with `/` then the code will return a null error. So in the above code, I have trimmed the `CreatedDate` field and replace the '/' with '-' and do remember to add leading zero into the day, month to avoid error in `ParseExact`.